# Regex match 2 alpha plus 6 digits in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a `regex` to match this pattern ( using C# )

My match must start with 2 alpha characters  ( MA or CA ) and must end with either 6 or seven numeric digits; such as CA123456 or MA123456 or MA1234567

Here is what I tried:

```
Regex.IsMatch(StringInput, @"^[MA]{2}|^[CA]{2}\d{6,7}?"))
```

Unfortunately, it seems to match most anything

Answer (score 5):

Try this pattern:

```
^[MC]A\d{6,7}$
```

The leading character class (`[MC]`) requires either an `M` or a `C` at the start of the string. Afterwards, `\d{6,7}` matches either 6 or 7 digits.

---

The issue with your pattern is the first alternative: `^[MA]{2}` matches any string that starts with `AA`, `AM`, `MA`, or `MM`. It doesn't require any following digits at all. Since the regex engine can match the first alternative for a string like *AA1234567* (matching the substring *AA*), it doesn't even attempt to find another match. This is why

> it seems to match most anything.

Comment: Very Thankful for this . .

Comment: @user2976464 Glad I could help. Please make sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are great usages of RegEx; in this particular case, using the built-in string functions of C# may be a better option:

1. Must start with either MA or CA
2. Must end with at least 6 digits (if there are 7, then there will be 6 digits)
3. Combining 1 and 2, the string must be at least 8 characters long

This would be the string version based on the above rules:

```
public static bool IsValid( string str )
{
    if( str.Length < 8 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( !str.StartsWith( "CA" ) && !str.StartsWith( "MA" ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    int result;
    string end = str.Substring( str.Length - 6 );
    bool isValid = int.TryParse( end, out result );

    return isValid;
}
```